# Deploy a HaxeFlixel game to a windows .exe file

Tags: deployment, haxe, flashdevelop, openfl, haxeflixel

I made a mini game with HaxeFlixel and OpenFL, It's worked great and now I want to put it on Game Jolt to check can it work or not, but to do that I need to change my whole project into executable, and I don't really know where I should start...

I looked it up and found some topic about Adobe AIR. Do I really need to use that to turn my Flixel project into an `.exe`? Can someone give me a little help here... I'm using FlashDevelop and Flixel for my game so right now my folder contains `assets`, `source`, `hxproj` file and a `xml` file. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a dropdown at the top of the window next to play button and the release type (`debug`, `release`). In that dropdown you can select your platform, in your case select native. The first time you compile is going to take awhile because you are compiling all the lib to C++.

The result is deploy in `bin/windows/windows`, there you can find your executable.

You can compile with command lines. Go to your folder and type `lime build windows`

Comment: Thanks, man. Really stupid I was only one step away from finding this folder... Still, many thanks!